# Discover Credit card in Australia

Tags: australia, payment-cards, discover-card

I am travelling to Australia in 2 weeks. I wanted to know if the Discover card is accepted at some places in Australia or not. Discover card is offering a $0 transaction fee, which is why I am asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discover cards are generally **not** accepted in Australia. However, this is changing slowly as more retailers accept UnionPay (which uses the same network as Discover) to cater for tourists from China.

The major credit cards accepted in Australia are Mastercard and Visa.  American Express and Diners Club are also accepted by some retailers.

Comment: Amex is fairly widely accepted, although often with an additional 2-3% surcharge.  However, Diners Club is next to unknown.

Comment: Discover should be accepted anywhere that Diners Club is. Discover cards even have a small Diners Club logo on the back.